# Google Maps Utilities IOS Pod error

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble adding Google Maps IOS Utilities (for marker clustering) to my swift xcode project with pods.
When I run `pod install` it fails with the following error:

> The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include static
>   binaries:
>   (/Users/warrick/Projects/orix/App/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework,
>   /Users/warrick/Projects/orix/App/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework,
>   and
>   /Users/warrick/Projects/orix/App/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework)

Google maps works fine, but as soon as I add the utilities it breaks.

What does this error message mean, and how can I go about resolving it?

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
workspace '../app'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

  # Firebase - used for notifications
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an issue that doesn’t have an out of the box solution due to Cocoapods limitations. The limitation occurs when an application is built in Swift, you are including `use_frameworks!` in your podfile, and are using a transitive dependency that is provided as a static library (such as `Google Maps`).

Becase Google will not provide a dynamic framework (until it supports iOS 7), the current workaround is to integrate `Google Maps IOS Utilities` manually into your project.

The integration steps are described here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/b721e95a500d0c9a4fd93738e83fc86c2a57ac89/Swift.md

> - Remove Google-Maps-iOS-Utils from the Podfile (if it is there).
>   In your project create a group named `'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'`.

- Download the repo into your local computer.
- Add the folders inside the src directory into your project by right clicking on the `'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'` group and selecting "Add Files to ..." (Make sure you select the target as your app target to avoid undefined symbols issue).
- Make sure "Use Header Map" is ON for your app target in XCode Settings (it is ON by default in XCode).
- Add a bridging header file with `#import "GMUMarkerClustering.h"` (note the relative path).
- Open the umbrella header GMUMarkerClustering.h (under the Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/Cluster group) and change all the import paths to relative. For example, change `#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUCluster.h>` to `#import "GMUCluster.h"`. (The 'Use Header Map' setting will resolve the relative path correctly).
- Build your project.
- That's it.

Comment: The link (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md) no longer exists. Other companies can build software that installs with CocoaPods (even GoogleMaps installs with a pod).

Comment: The instructions from the Swift.md provided by Ilya are correct and work for Xcode 11, Swift 5.

Comment: @Ilya Shvedikov Where did you add the bridging header file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install pod, error disappeared after I removed use_frameworks! from pod file because our project is in swift and added following lines to podfile
pod 'GoogleMaps' # Objective-C pod
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils'

Comment: Later on I faced issues , so switched back to manual integration and it worked thank you!!.. https://stackoverflow.com/users/7261633/ilya-shvedikov

Comment: thank-you the explanation link is no longer active so your steps saved a lot of time

Comment: Glad to hear that happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

i found the error on my project, it was the version difference in podfile and deployment info. so i changed the version in deployment info as like podfile, now the error **got cleared** .

[image]

[image]